# How to make a border for an image with a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to take an image and make a function `addborder(y)` in JavaScript to make the image have a yellow border. The purpose is to see how to do things to an image using JavaScript.

```
<!--HTML-->

<img id="img" src="http://pre01.deviantart.net/3d38/th/pre/f/2012/298/5/a/dubstep_wallpaper_by_theblazia-d5iwj4c.png" alt="boom boom boom" >

<p id="here"></p>

<Script>

var y = document.getElementById("img"); //I think it stores "img" as var y.

function addborder(x) {
  for (var pixel of x.values()) {
    //loop to change "img" border pixels to yellow
    if (
      pixel.getX() < 50 ||
      pixel.getX() > x.getWidth() - 50 ||
      pixel.getY() < 200 ||
      pixel.getY() > x.getHeight() - 50
    ) {
      pixel.setRed(255);
      pixel.setGreen(255);
      pixel.setBlue(255);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = x; //should print in paragraph?

  //do I need a return statement??
}
```

Comment: Javascript / DOM does not work like that.  Learn the basics of Javascript syntax, and learn about CSS and/or `Canvas`.

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you won't need to write a comment on each closing-brace explaining what it closes. Try https://prettier.io/playground/ for some help

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would just make use of the **[`.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** to alter the CSS directly through JavaScript; you don't need to make use of a complex function that manipulates the pixels themselves.

In the following example, I demonstrate creating a simple border using `.style.border`:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('img');
image.style.border = 'thick solid #0000FF';
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/100">
```

Hope this helps! :)